# how to replace users input in php

Tags: php

I pray that my question isn't confusing. I have made a search engine where people can search the city and state like so "Atlanta, GA" What I want is no matter how they type it whether it's like Atlanta,GA or Atlanta GA or Atlanta, GA it will still find the results. Now I tried doing this with PHP STR and I don't know if this is right. Here is my code. Thanks.

```
 $userinput=$request->input('cityandstate');

 $stq=str_replace(",",", ", $userinput);
```

Comment: Does your search engine require the city and state to be like <city> comma space <state>?

Comment: yes it does but sometimes you have people that don't that rule so I just want to be prepare for that

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to get the user input into the exact form required by your search engine. `preg_replace` let's you allow for all sorts of inputs with multiple spaces and with or without commas:

```
$userinputs =array("Atlanta  GA", "Atlanta,GA", "Atlanta , GA", "Atlanta, GA ", " Atlanta   ,GA");
foreach ($userinputs as $userinput) {
   $stq = preg_replace('/^\s*(\w+)\s*,?\s*(\w+)\s*$/', '$1, $2', $userinput);
   echo "$stq\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Atlanta, GA
Atlanta, GA
Atlanta, GA
Atlanta, GA
Atlanta, GA
```

Answer (score 0):

This will replace any comma in the string with nothing.

```
$stq = str_replace(",", "", $userinput);
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
str_replace ( mixed $search , mixed $replace , mixed $subject [, int &$count ] )
```

This will not help you if a user inputs Atlanta - GA and you may be better served by using a preg_replace
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Comment: Okay I will try that

Comment: I tried it and it worked, quick question can I also do something like this Miami, fl replaced with Miami,fl? I tried doing this  $stq=str_replace(", ", ",",$userinputt);

Comment: its not working. I did  $stq=str_replace(",  ", ",", $userinputt); its not replacing Miami, fl with Miami,fl

Comment: It appears you have a spelling mistake? $userinputt has an extra t? This worked for me.

$userinput = "Atlanta, GA";

$newString = str_replace(", ", ",", $userinput);

echo $newString;

Comment: but $userinputt is what I named the variable

Comment: Copy the code that I wrote above and try it. It definitely worked for me.